# Finding the difference between columns in matrix without loops

Tags: matlab

I have the results from an iterative process, where the results from each iteration is placed beside eachother, like this:

```
res = 
   43.7826   38.8460   38.6889   38.6912   38.6915
  107.0735   98.5577   98.1212   98.1170   98.1175
 -134.6218 -131.6938 -131.5378 -131.5352 -131.5352
 -105.9498 -103.1403 -102.9195 -102.9139 -102.9139
```

What I want to do is create one matrix that shows the difference between each column, and one matrix that shows the percentage change from one column to the next.

This is obviously simple to do using loops, but is there a clever way to do this without loops (maybe using some built-in Matlab functions)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command diff(...) performes the difference:

```
diff_res = diff(res,1,2)
```

in this case the difference of the first order in the second dimension (columns).
After you can compute the percentage:

```
per_res = diff_res(:,1:4)./res(:,1:4).*100
```